# Equivalent of postinit{} block in JavaFX 2.0

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

In JavaFX 2.0 is there some equivalent of postinit{} block from JavaFX 1.3?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Java Constructor](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/oop/constructors/constructor.html) with no arguments is roughly equivalent to a postinit block.

Comment: constructor of the Controller class ?

Comment: No dhroove, any Java class constructor, not just Controller class constructors.  Both Java constructors and JavaFXScript `postinit` are language level concepts, not concepts of any particular type of class.  Anyway, this question matters little as JavaFX 1.3 is completely obsolete by now, so very few people would be using it.

Comment: So is there any postinit kind of thing javafx 2 ? I need some method which is invoked immediately after the public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) { } method of the controller.

Comment: I have stated my complete problem use case is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20091341/javafx-how-to-load-big-file-in-background-during-initialize-method-of-javafx