# How to load big file in background during initialize() method of Javafx?

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, asynchronous, javafx-2

My javafx desktop application load and big text file during the initialization of the application in the

```
 @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

      loadAppConfigurationFile();
   }


   private void loadAppConfigurationFile() {

        Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() throws InterruptedException {

                //read file and do some operation
                return null;
            }
        };
        new Thread(task).start();
    }
```

But the problem here is my application GUI doesn't appear till this process it over. I invoked this file reading in another thread excepting that my GUI stage/scene will be loaded first and their I can show some loading message till that file is loaded in the system.

Kindly tell the exact workaround for this.

Comment: i do same its working perfectly... can you show your main class ???

Comment: If you put a debugger anywhere in code in Task, does your gui is getting loaded. In my case it is not getting loaded until it call is finished.

Comment: i am give a answer which i do from oracle documentation

Comment: can you show inner code  ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i try this and its work easily...here `bar` is a progress bar

```
    @FXML
    void initialize () {
        assert bar != null : "fx:id=\"bar\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Check.fxml'.";
        loadAppConfigurationFile();
    }

    private void loadAppConfigurationFile () {
        Task task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() throws InterruptedException {
                int max = 1000000;
                for (int i = 1; i <= max; i = i + 10) {
                    if (isCancelled()) {
                        break;
                    }
                    updateProgress(i, max);
                    System.out.println("somethings is here");
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
        bar.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
        new Thread(task).start();
    }
```